# Filter select in SQLite using single query

Tags: sqlite, select, case

I need to query a table like this:

```
select phrase_id
from direct_words 
where knowledge_id = X and dictionary_word_id = Y;
```

but I only want to retrieve the rows where the same pair (knowledge_id = X and dictionary_word_id = Y) **doesn't** exist in another table (top_words). This can be done, applying the query:

```
select top_id from top_words where knowledge_id = X and dictionary_word_id = Y;
```

for each returned result from the first query and rejecting if the second query has a row count above 0.

Is this possible to do in a single query to SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the left join as Andrey suggested, or ...AND NOT EXISTS ( select x from TOP_WORDS where .... )

Comment: Thank you. The left join as Andrey suggested can't be used, since phrase_id doesn't exist in top_words table.

Answer (score 0):

select dw.phrase_id
from direct_words dw
left outer join top_words tw on dw.phrase_id=tw.phrase_id
where dw.knowledge_id = X and dw.dictionary_word_id = Y and tw.phrase_id is NULL

Comment: The table top_words has no phrase_id field, so the join can't be done that way. The common fields are knowledge_id and dictionary_word_id. It can't be done that way.